# Add UIPanGesture only horizontally on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I need to add an UIPanGestureRecognizer to swipe horizontally 3 views. 
How can I add UIPangesture only horizontally to an UIView?

Comment: Doesn't UISwipeGesture work for your purpose? It has a direction attribute associated with it which you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a pan gesture recognizer, you usually have some code that looks something like this:

```
CGPoint translate = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    CGRect newFrame = self.currentViewFrame;
    newFrame.origin.x += translate.x;
    newFrame.origin.y += translate.y;
    self.touched.frame = newFrame; // touched is the view I'm dragging
```

If you just leave out the line, newFrame.origin.y += translate.y, then it will only pan in the horizontal direction.

Comment: Thank you, it works properly!!! I only changed it:         `newFrame.origin.x =  translate.x;` but now it's ok.

Thank you!!!